# Comment body not displaying

Tags: comments

I have an interesting problem where the comment body does not appear with the comment. The field wrapping is in the HTML but the content portion is always blank.

This problem occurs regardless of the theme, eg. the same result with Bartik.

The database entry for a comment is:

```
+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------+----------+
| cid   | comment_type | uuid                                 | langcode |
+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------+----------+
| 35044 |              | b6328985-9e15-46e4-a55d-8285e530ee55 | en       |
+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------+----------+
```

and the body:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------------+---------------------+
| bundle  | deleted | entity_id | revision_id | langcode | delta | comment_body_value | comment_body_format |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------------+---------------------+
| comment |       0 |     35044 |       35044 | en       |     0 | <p>Test text</p>
 | basic_html          |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

The comment displays on the node view as:

```
j ayen green

Mon, 05/20/2019 - 14:39

Test
```

And displays on the comment edit form as:

```
Edit comment Test
Open Primary tabs configuration options
View comment Edit(active tab) Delete Likes
Subject
Test
```

The comment field on the content type entry is:

```
Comments    field_comments  Comments
```

The Manage Display entry for Comments is:

```
FIELD     LABEL     FORMAT

Comment   Hidden    Default
```

The field on the comment type is:

```
LABEL   MACHINE NAME    FIELD TYPE  
Comment comment_body    Text (formatted, long)
```

And the HTML is:

```
<article data-quickedit-entity-id="comment/35044" data-comment-user-id="2" class="contextual-region js-comment comment">
<mark class="hidden" data-comment-timestamp="1558377554"></mark>

<footer class="attribution">

  <div class="comment-submitted">
    <p class="commenter-name">
      <a title="View user profile." href="/users/j-ayen-green" lang="" about="/users/j-ayen-green" typeof="schema:Person" property="schema:name" datatype="">j ayen green</a>
    </p>
    <p class="comment-time">
      Mon, 05/20/2019 - 14:39
    </p>
    <p class="comment-permalink">
      <a href="/comment/35044#comment-35044" hreflang="en">Permalink</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>
  <div class="comment-text">
    <div class="comment-arrow"></div>
      <h3><a href="/comment/35044#comment-35044" class="permalink" rel="bookmark" hreflang="en">Test</a></h3>
      <div data-contextual-id="comment:comment=35044:changed=1558377554&amp;langcode=en" data-contextual-token="KOoBECnJMIEjGXKwxb9Of3jmUIP7X_nacwAme2qzwio"></div>
        <div  class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Make sure in [Mange Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFe6l.png) it's not disabled.

Comment: It’s not disabled in either the node comment field  manage display or the comment type manage display.